# Sencha Touch & Sencha Architect: Nested Models

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Using the Sencha Architect, I am facing the following problem in Sencha Touch 2: 
I can define models, read them from a JSONp proxy, no problem, but how can I define a model which itself contains an array of another model?

The data is loaded fine, but the array of "sub"models is just a plain JS object, I cannot use any getters for instance. There is no link with the Ext Model definition...

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure to define the relations between models using [associations](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.association.Association). Define getters and setters on the associations where needed. Then, load the data using a store which is referring to you top-level model. 
Call the getters of associated data on the store once loaded.